# Fading in and out with Click

Tags: jquery, fade

I would want the quotes to start fading in/out and get to the next one after just clicking the screen. The way it is now, the first quote starts before I get to that page and it's a bit confusing. It's a scrolling website.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2500)
            .delay(2200)
            .fadeOut(4500, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to wait for a click then don't automatically run `showNextQuote()` on the last line.  Add it into a click event:

```
$(document).on('click', showNextQuote );
```

To show the first automatically:

```
++quoteIndex;
quotes.eq(quoteIndex).fadeIn(2500);
```

Then it will require a click for the next one to start.

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `$(document).ready(fn)` alias `$(function() {})` for IIFE `(function() {})()` ; `.fadeTo()` for `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` ; assigning `click` event to `$(window)` with `showNextQuote` set as handler for `click` event

```js
$(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeTo(2500, 1)
            .delay(2200)
            .fadeTo(4500, 0);
    }

    $(window).on("click", showNextQuote);

});
```

```css
body {
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
}

.quotes {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
click
<div class="quotes">a</div>
<div class="quotes">b</div>
<div class="quotes">c</div>
<div class="quotes">d</div>
```